Unable to delete record from a underlying table when there is an equal view using Entity Framework Core and C#
I use Entity Framework Core in an ASP.NET C# project.
I have a table in the database called Sales, and a view called HotSales.
The view contains only the hot sales from the Sales table + more info from another table using JOIN.
In the DbContext class, I have a DbSet object for each of them.
I try to delete a row from the Sales table like this:
Sale sale = _context.Sales.FindAsync(id);
_context.Sales.Remove(sale as Sale);
_context.SaveChanges();

I get an error about HotSales type:

The entity type 'HotSales' is not mapped to a table, therefore the entities cannot be persisted to the database. Call 'ToTable' in 'OnModelCreating' to map it to a table.

Why does Entity Framework Core recognizes the Sales object as HotSales? How can I delete the row?

Can you show full exception callstack?

Show us how you've configured EF Core for these two entities

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
modelBuilder.Entity().ToView("HotSales");
}
public DbSet Sales { get; set; }
public DbSet HotSales { get; set; }

Likely the problem is in the context itself. You have very likely created a FK relation to the hotsales table. And then some sort of cascade effect on delete cannot correctly propagate to the hotsales "table" as you likely have defined it.
Please show us the context code for the <Sales> and <HotSales> entity definitions from the dbcontext.
That alone should tell you what is wrong. Your software is treating the view as a table. That is the specific problem you are having.

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{ base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); modelBuilder.Entity().ToView("HotSales"); } public DbSet Sales { get; set; } public DbSet HotSales { get; set; }
